# Can I live in Russia for the whole 3 years on a 3 year multiple entry visa?

Tags: visa, immigration, us-citizens, russia

<sub>I posted this on the travel section and they told me to repost in here for visa questions.</sub>

---

I'm an American citizen considering moving to Russia for a little bit. Is there any restriction on that 3 year multiple entry visa that would prohibit me from actually just staying in Russia for the whole 3 years?

I checked on [VisaHQ](https://www.visahq.com/russia/) and didn't see any restrictions, but I am just checking to make sure it isn't like a "90 days in, 90 days out" policy.

Comment: What category of visa is it?  Most categories do not allow you to work.  Do you have enough money to live in Russia for three years without working?  The advice from [Travel.SE] was not to ask the same question here (because the answer to this question is that you can't stay in Russia for three years using that visa; you need some other kind of visa), but to ask about what kinds of visa are available that would allow you to live in Russia for an extended period.

Comment: You are limited to 180 days on a valid Russian multi entry visa (in a US passport). All Russian multi entry tourist visas clearly have the duration printed on them (180 days). My advice is to follow the rules in Russia as they take immigration very seriously.

Comment: You can view a multi entry student visa for UK here, and you can see the duration section: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bd/UKstudentvisa.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You would only be able to stay for 6 months at a time but anecdotal evidence suggests that the 6 month period can be "reset" by leaving and re-entering Russia.

You can read the document regarding the agreement linked from the Russian Consulate in Houston's [website](https://rusconhouston.mid.ru/en_US/general-visa-information) https://rusconhouston.mid.ru/en_US/general-visa-information (click on Agreement between the Russian Federation and the United States of America").

> Nationals of each Party shall as a rule be issued multiple-entry visas for a stay of no more than 6 months starting from the date of each entry that are valid for 36 months from the date of issue as long as reciprocity is maintained: by the Russian Federation - business, private, humanitarian and tourist visas, and by the United States of America — В1/B2 visas.

However if you intend to work in Russia you would need a work permit.

Answer (score 1):

Russian tourist visa has 30 days limitation of staying without exit.

from ФЗ-114 "О порядке въезда из Российской Федерации и выезда в Российскую Федерацию"

The foreigner without registration could stay in Russia 90 days per every 180 days.

from 115-ФЗ "О правовом положении иностранных граждан в Российской Федерации"